# Parabolic subalgebra conjugate under Weyl group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a semisimple (or reductive (using the definition of Knapp)) Lie group. Then any two minimal parabolic subalgebras resp. subgroups are conjugated under $\operatorname{Ad}(K)$ resp. $K$ ($K$ being maximally compact in $G$).

My question is: Is it sufficient to take $k\in K$ in the normalizer $N_K(\mathfrak a)$ of $\mathfrak a$ in $K$ (resp. the Weyl group $N_K(\mathfrak a)/Z_K(\mathfrak a)$), so that any two conjugated parabolics differ only be another choice of positive system in $\mathfrak a$? Here, $\mathfrak a$ denotes a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak p$, the $-1$-eigenspace of the Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k\oplus\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Probably you mean _minimal_ parabolics?

Comment: @paulgarrett You're right, I edited my question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: And "minimal parabolic" e.g. in the split case would be a Borel? Because then isn't $G=SL_2(\mathbb R)$ already a counterexample: the Borel subalgebras $\pmatrix{a&b\\0&-a}$ and $\pmatrix{r&c+r\\c-r&-r}$ in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ are not conjugate by something in the Weyl group, and have different "tori" $\mathfrak{a} = \pmatrix{a&0\\0&-a}$ vs $\mathfrak{a}' = \pmatrix{0&c\\c&0}$.

Comment: @Nightgap: Have you seen my latest comment? I mean, one issue is that there are many choices for $\mathfrak a$ to begin with, and then it's kind of clear that $N_K(\mathfrak a)$ for one chosen $\mathfrak a$ will not conjugate them. Maybe you want to restrict to those minimal parabolics which contain the same $\mathfrak a$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Sorry for answering so late, I didn't see your latest comment. No, I don not want to restrict to one chosen $\mathfrak a$. In the example you gave: Are the two Borel algebras still conjugate by something in $G$? If so, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient.

Example:

$G= SL_2(\mathbb R)$, $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$,

$\mathfrak k = \mathfrak{so}_2(\mathbb R) = \{ \pmatrix{0&\theta \\ -\theta & 0} \vert \theta \in \mathbb R \}$, $\mathfrak p = \{ \pmatrix{a & c \\ c & -a} \vert \; a,c \in \mathbb R \}$,

$K= SO_2(\mathbb R) = \{ R_\theta := \pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta) } \vert \;\theta \in \mathbb R \}$.

Now the first problem is that there are various choices for maximal abelian subspaces inside $\mathfrak p$ -- actually, each one-dimensional subspace of $\mathfrak p$ is one. The standard choice is

$$\mathfrak a := \{ \pmatrix{a & 0 \\ 0 & -a} \vert \; a \in \mathbb R \},$$

but

$$\mathfrak c := \{ \pmatrix{0 & c \\ c & 0} \vert \; c \in \mathbb R \}$$

theoretically is not better or worse. Now a well-known minimal parabolic (= Borel) subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ is

$$\mathfrak b_a := \{ \pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & -a} \vert \; a, b \in \mathbb R \}$$

which contains $\mathfrak a$; but another Borel subalgebra is

$$\mathfrak b_c := \{ \pmatrix{r & c+r \\ c-r & -r} \vert \; c,r \in \mathbb R \}$$

which contains $\mathfrak c$. And you can check that $\mathfrak b_a$ and $\mathfrak b_c$ are indeed conjugate via $K$ as predicted by the result quoted in your first paragraph, namely, with $R_{\pi/4} = \dfrac12 \sqrt{2} \cdot \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1} \in K $ we have

$$ R_{\pi/4} \cdot \mathfrak b_a \cdot R_{\pi/4}^{-1} = \mathfrak b_c$$
including
$$ R_{\pi/4} \cdot \mathfrak a \cdot R_{\pi/4}^{-1} = \mathfrak c$$

i.e. $R_{\pi/4} \not \in N_K(\mathfrak a)$, and of course nothing in $N_K(\mathfrak a)$ could possibly conjugate $\mathfrak b_a$ and $\mathfrak b_c$ (as $\mathfrak a \cap \mathfrak b_c = \{0\}$).

Indeed $N_K(\mathfrak a)$ contains just four elements, $ \pm \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$ and $\pm \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$; the first two centralize $\mathfrak a$, so the Weyl group here indeed just has two elements, the non-trivial one being represented by $R_{\pi/2} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$, and this conjugates $\mathfrak b_a$ and

$$\mathfrak b_a^- := \{ \pmatrix{a & 0 \\ b & -a} \vert \; a, b \in \mathbb R \}$$

which seem to be the only two minimal parabolics *which contain $\mathfrak a$*, and these two really correspond just to the other choice of the one positive root in the root system to $\mathfrak a$. But since you asked about general minimal parabolics ...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! So the minimal parabolics containing a fixed $\mathfrak a$ are conjugate by the Weyl-group. However, if two minimal parabolics contain different 'tori' they are never conjugate by the Weyl-group but still conjugate by $K$.